# How do I interpret these beta estimates in a multilevel-model?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis

For my undergrad thesis, I am currently trying to build a multilevel-model with two levels but I'm having a hard time as none of my courses prepared me for this kind of modeling. My main problem is that I'm unsure regarding the interpretation of my output and if I did everything correctly, so far. I'll just present to you what I have achieved until now:

My DV is "stfdem" and ranges from 1-11. My professor said that despite its rather ordinal nature I may treat this as a metric variable. My L1-predictors are age, gender, income and education levels, all of which (except gndr which remains a dummy) have been transformed to a scale from 0-10 and then mean-centered. My L2-predictor is ssec (it's a % of GDP) which also has been transformed and mean-centered.

```html
cntry stfdem gndr       agea        inc         edu     ssec
   AT     11    0 -0.6660629 -1.4779334 -1.02005147 2.662121
   AT      6    1  1.3339371 -0.4779334 -1.02005147 2.662121
   AT      6    1 -1.6660629  0.5220666 -1.02005147 2.662121
   AT      1    1 -0.6660629  1.5220666 -1.02005147 2.662121
   AT      4    0 -1.6660629 -0.4779334 -1.02005147 2.662121
```

N is over 9000 for L1, but only 27 for L2 (I am aware that this may have adverse effects on my results, but that's a problem for another day).

**First question:** Is there a problem with my data to begin with? Any help, hints and notes would be appreciated.

Now, using the `lmer` package, I created a random-intercept-model:

```
m1 <- lmer(stfdem ~ agea + gndr + inc + edu + (1 | cntry), data = dat)
```

which, for my betas, yields me the following:

```html
Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 6.423e+00  3.478e-01 5.044e+00  18.469 7.94e-06 ***
agea        1.243e-02  1.385e-02 9.317e+03   0.897   0.3695    
gndr        8.723e-02  4.941e-02 9.316e+03   1.765   0.0775 .  
inc         6.615e-02  9.760e-03 9.317e+03   6.777 1.30e-11 ***
edu         5.928e-02  1.489e-02 9.319e+03   3.981 6.91e-05 ***
```

**Second question**: How do I interpret these estimates? I have only encountered betas this small in log-linear models, where one multiplies them by 100 in order to get an interpretation in %. But this does not apply here? Also, directly interpreting them as the estimated influence of their respective variable seems like a very small effect to me.

I appreciate any help with my questions and I am sorry if some aspects of my question(s) are pretty basic, but I've worked on these models for 10 hours straight and my brain now feels much like porridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> N is over 9000 for L1, but only 27 for L2 (I am aware that this may have adverse effects on my results, but that's a problem for another day).

That is not a problem.

> First question: Is there a problem with my data to begin with? Any help, hints and notes would be appreciated.

Your data is in the right format to fit a mixed model. However, I question why you decided to rescale the variables in the way you did ? This makes the interpretation much harder than it needs to be.

> Second question: How do I interpret these estimates?

The interpretation is the same as for any linear model. Each estimate is the expected change in the outcome variables that is associated with a 1 unit change in that predictor variable, leaving the other variables unchanged. So each 1 unit change in `agea` is associated with a 0.012 change in `stfdem`. If you had not rescaled `agea` then (assuming the original scale is years) then it would be for a  1 *year* change.